# Validating html with php

Tags: php, html, validation

Something is wrong with my print `"<option value...";` 
line of php code.

It keeps generating error messages:
an attribute value specification must be an attribute value literal unless SHORTTAG YES is specified

```
<option value = Addition>Addition</option>
<and so on...>
```

Okay, so how do  i fix this line of code:

```
//foreach loop to cycle through the array
      foreach ($testFiles as $myFile)
      {
        $fileBase = substr($myFile, 0, strlen($myFile) - 5);
       **//Problem here:**
        print "<option value = $fileBase>$fileBase</option>\n";
      } // end foreach
```

such that's it's html compliant, the php code works fine, I just need validation on the html, cause you can't validate php, and the variable $fileBase references an html file, in this case Addition would be one of the files allotted to $fileBase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print "<option value = \"$fileBase\">$fileBase</option>\n";
```

Should do it

Comment: ..as all attributes must be enclosed in (double) quotes according to the XHTML spec.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: Can you point me to the XHTML spec document about double quotes? I was under the impression single quote is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "<option value='$fileBase'>$fileBase</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other options:

You could use printf:

```
printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $fileBase, $fileBase);
```

A [here-doc](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
echo <<<HTML
    <option value="$fileBase">$fileBase</option>
HTML;
```

You could drop out of PHP temporarily (generally a good technique, but not very pretty here):

```
<?
foreach ($testFiles as $myFile) {
    $fileBase = substr($myFile, 0, strlen($myFile) - 5);
    ?>
    <option value="<?= htmlentities($fileBase) ?>"><?= htmlentities($fileBase) ?></option>
    <?
}
?>
```

But really, what you should be doing is using one of the many templating systems out there, and not mixing HTML in with your code.